# How to integrate apim with wso2 micro intergrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-integrator

Integrate apim with micro integator

How to integrate apim with micro integator without using integration studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add a REST API created on EI to APIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74473644/is-it-possible-to-add-a-rest-api-created-on-ei-to-apim)

Comment: How to integrate api i have created on my own .That api should integrated with mi for schema validation and meta info generations

Comment: Please add more context to your question when posting it. Thanks!

Comment: i downloaded the wso2 Micro integrator and apmi . Two component are up and running Now i need to Connect the api-manager to micro integrator through service catalog in api-manager but i need some clarity, how the two components are integrating  with each other . 
am seeing  micro-indicator dashboard also.    Under Micro Integator removed Comments in deployement.toml  I couldn't find any logs in log folder 
I have this section:
[[service_catalog]]
apim_host = "https://localhost:9443"
enable = true
username = "admin"
password = "admin"

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created a back-end API, then you don't need Micro-integrator, and you can directly expose that API through the API Manager. The API Manager can add schema validation as well.

If you need to implement additional message mediations, message transformations, and service orchestration on top of your existing back-end services, then you can do that using Micro-integrator and expose that as an API using API Manager.

Please see - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/integration-quick-start-guide/

Comment: How my apim and microintergator will be connected??

Comment: I have installed locally.Do i need make changes in toml.If any documentation  regarding apim integration with mi kindly share

Answer (score 0):

Micro Integrator is already embedded with the API Manager 4.1 .If you need to add some transformations to your API that you didn't found in the API Manger ,then you have to do it in the Integration Studio and then publish it to the Publisher Portal using service catalog feature.

You can follow this documentation

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/service-catalog-tutorial/

Comment: Without  using integration studio .i deployed api in apim(Deployed) and subcribed but couldn't find it in micro integrator.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating API Manager and Micro-integrator will be done via the Service Catalog by adding the following configurations in MI deployment .toml.

```
[[service_catalog]]
apim_host = "https://localhost:9443"
enable = true
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
```

Once you have created the integration service and deployed it in the Micro-integrator, you only need to start the two servers (APIM server and the Micro-integrator server).

More information - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/working-with-service-catalog/

Comment: Is there an way without using integration studio ?

Comment: Are you referring to development or deployment?

Comment: i have api written in node js.i need to use that api in apim.Do schema valiadation ,converts to json also in mi.is there an way without using integration studio